# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Ethereum breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          6
Users destroyed                                   3          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           195      2,685
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                5        510
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        545      3,853
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                3      1,789
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                37      7,122
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              365      7,469
Tags merged                                       4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          1
Tag synonyms created                              4          0
Tag highlight language set                        4          0
Questions reopened                               12          9
Questions protected                              35         40
Questions migrated                                6          1
Questions flagged⁴                                0        493
Questions closed                                444      1,561
Question flags handled⁴                         140        353
Posts unlocked                                    0          2
Posts undeleted                                  12        168
Posts locked                                      0         59
Posts deleted⁵                                1,071      3,565
Posts bumped                                      0      8,710
Comments undeleted                                4          0
Comments flagged                                  0      1,046
Comments deleted⁶                               348      2,659
Comment flags handled                           185        861
Answers flagged                                  12      3,479
Answer flags handled                          2,617        874
All comments on a post moved to chat             22          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...